# How to serialize fixed array of struct in rust using serde lib?

Tags: rust, serialization, serde

Im trying to serialize a fixed array of data (a struct) inside another struct.
both struct derive Serialize, Deserialize from Serde lib. but im getting errors with the second struct, saying `the trait bound` [Acceleration; 300]: Serialize `is not satisfied`

```rust
use serde_json;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::{Read, Write, Result, Error, ErrorKind};

mod utils;

trait MPU60X0Data {
    fn saveData(&self, file_name: &str) -> Result<()>;

    fn loadData(&self, file_name: &str) -> Result<()>;
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Acceleration {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Gyroscope {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

// 5 entries every second for 1 minute
const NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN : usize = 5 * 60;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct Data {
    accelerations : [Acceleration; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
    gyroscope_angles: [Gyroscope; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
}

impl MPU60X0Data for Data {
    fn saveData(&self, file_name: &str) -> Result<()> {
        if utils::path_exists(&file_name) {
            Error::new(ErrorKind::AlreadyExists ,"The specified file exist and cannot be mofiled.");
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    fn loadData(&self, file_name: &str) -> Result<()> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

and im getting errors like this on build

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Acceleration; 300]: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:35:21
     |
35   |     accelerations : [Acceleration; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
     |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[Acceleration; 300]`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserialize<'de>`:
               &'a [u8]
               [T; 0]
               [T; 10]
               [T; 11]
               [T; 12]
               [T; 13]
               [T; 14]
               [T; 15]
             and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `next_element`
    --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\de\mod.rs:1729:12
     |
1729 |         T: Deserialize<'de>,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `SeqAccess::next_element`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Gyroscope; 300]: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:36:23
     |
36   |     gyroscope_angles: [Gyroscope; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
     |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[Gyroscope; 300]`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserialize<'de>`:
               &'a [u8]
               [T; 0]
               [T; 10]
               [T; 11]
               [T; 12]
               [T; 13]
               [T; 14]
               [T; 15]
             and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `next_element`
    --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\de\mod.rs:1729:12
     |
1729 |         T: Deserialize<'de>,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `SeqAccess::next_element`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Acceleration; 300]: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:35:21
     |
35   |     accelerations : [Acceleration; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
     |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[Acceleration; 300]`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserialize<'de>`:
               &'a [u8]
               [T; 0]
               [T; 10]
               [T; 11]
               [T; 12]
               [T; 13]
               [T; 14]
               [T; 15]
             and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `next_value`
    --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\de\mod.rs:1868:12
     |
1868 |         V: Deserialize<'de>,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `MapAccess::next_value`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Gyroscope; 300]: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:36:23
     |
36   |     gyroscope_angles: [Gyroscope; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
     |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[Gyroscope; 300]`
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserialize<'de>`:
               &'a [u8]
               [T; 0]
               [T; 10]
               [T; 11]
               [T; 12]
               [T; 13]
               [T; 14]
               [T; 15]
             and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `next_value`
    --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\de\mod.rs:1868:12
     |
1868 |         V: Deserialize<'de>,
     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `MapAccess::next_value`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Acceleration; 300]: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:35:5
   |
35 |     accelerations : [Acceleration; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[Acceleration; 300]`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserialize<'de>`:
             &'a [u8]
             [T; 0]
             [T; 10]
             [T; 11]
             [T; 12]
             [T; 13]
             [T; 14]
             [T; 15]
           and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `_::_serde::__private::de::missing_field`
  --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\private\de.rs:22:8
   |
22 |     V: Deserialize<'de>,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `missing_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Gyroscope; 300]: Deserialize<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:36:5
   |
36 |     gyroscope_angles: [Gyroscope; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `[Gyroscope; 300]`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Deserialize<'de>`:
             &'a [u8]
             [T; 0]
             [T; 10]
             [T; 11]
             [T; 12]
             [T; 13]
             [T; 14]
             [T; 15]
           and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `_::_serde::__private::de::missing_field`
  --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\private\de.rs:22:8
   |
22 |     V: Deserialize<'de>,
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `missing_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Acceleration; 300]: Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:33:23
     |
33   | #[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
     |                       ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `[Acceleration; 300]`
34   | struct Data {
35   |     accelerations : [Acceleration; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
     |     ------------- required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `Serialize`:
               [T; 0]
               [T; 10]
               [T; 11]
               [T; 12]
               [T; 13]
               [T; 14]
               [T; 15]
               [T; 16]
             and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `_::_serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
    --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\ser\mod.rs:1901:12
     |
1901 |         T: Serialize;
     |            ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `SerializeStruct::serialize_field`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `[Gyroscope; 300]: Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src\main.rs:33:23
     |
33   | #[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
     |                       ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `[Gyroscope; 300]`
...
36   |     gyroscope_angles: [Gyroscope; NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES_PER_MIN],
     |     ---------------- required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `Serialize`:
               [T; 0]
               [T; 10]
               [T; 11]
               [T; 12]
               [T; 13]
               [T; 14]
               [T; 15]
               [T; 16]
             and 26 others
note: required by a bound in `_::_serde::ser::SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
    --> C:\Users\Vasu\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\serde-1.0.164\src\ser\mod.rs:1901:12
     |
1901 |         T: Serialize;
     |            ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `SerializeStruct::serialize_field`
```